# MochaUI Post data and MochaUI.updateContent

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm playing around with mochaUI and am having a hard time getting POST data to work correctly. I have a form and a submit button. I am using MochaUI.updateContent to work within panels. In the main panel, I have the form and the following js:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$('stp1btn').addEvent('click', function(e){
    MochaUI.updateContent({
        element: $('mainPanel'),
        method: 'post',
        data: "w=1",
        url: '/postFile.php',
        title: 'Test Post Stuff durrrrrr',
        padding: { top: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8, left: 8 }
    });
});
</script>
```

Which posts to a page which then is supposed to update the same panel. However, I can't get it to post correctly. Even in the above example where the sample data is simply "w=1", what is actually getting posted is "w=1" in addition to what looks like one of the mootools js files included within mochaUI:

This is the Form Data from Firebug:

```
0:w
1:=
2:1
$family[name]:string
test:function (a,b){return((typeof a=="string")?new RegExp(a,b):a).test(this);
}
contains:function (a,b){return(b)?(b this b).indexOf(b a b)>-1:this.indexOf(a)>-1;}
clean:function (){return this.replace(/\s /g," ").trim();
}
camelCase:function (){return this.replace(/-\D/g,function(a){return a.charAt(1).toUpperCase();});}
hyphenate:function (){return this.replace(/[A-Z]/g,function(a){return("-" a.charAt(0).toLowerCase());
});}[SNIP]
```

I am using a framework (codeigniter) which disallows query strings thereby preventing the post data from even seeing the destination php file.

The html on the page is all correct.

I've tried surrounding the data with both quotations and apostrophes.

I searched the nether-regions of the internet looking for answers. Found tits instead--so it wasn't a total wash.

If anyone could lend some insight into how/what would be injecting the js into the post data, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try this:

```
$('stp1btn').addEvent('click', function(e){
    MochaUI.updateContent({
        element: $('mainPanel'),
        method: 'post',
        data: { w: 1 },
        url: '/postFile.php',
        title: 'Test Post Stuff durrrrrr',
        padding: { top: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8, left: 8 }
    });
});
```

the mootools request does work with an object literal or otherwise for data - even can serialize a form element, so data: `document.id("formel")` is usually fine.

if the subclassing by mochaui is ok, then it should work.

Comment: Thanks Dimitar. So does the data param expect json? Also, I tried getting it to serialize the form as that is the end result I wanted. In your example, you have document.id('form'). Is that the exact way? i.e. I tried data: $('form') which didn't work. In your example, what does document.id refer to? Or is that just mootools equivalent of jquery's $ ? Much thanks.

Comment: depends on the ver of mootools. if you are on 1.2 - prior to 1.2.3, which is what shipped with mochaui, then document.id wont be anything - it is since then that $ became an alias for document.id so it does not go into conflict. data expects an object, a from element or a value pair query string. i would recommend grabbing mochaui from github latest, its waaaay past the demo ver 0.97

Comment: Yeah, I'm running the latest. I think that's wht had me confused--I'd seen $ used in a few examples. It's irrelevant now that it's working, but isn't what I used in the question a value pair query string? "w=1"? For the record I also tried one like "w=1&d=8" with the same result where it POST's part of a js file. Thanks again.

Comment: nah, like so: `new Request({options...}).send("foo=bar&bar=banana")`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$('stp1btn').addEvent('click', function(e){
    var myRequest = new Request({
        url: '/le_formDerp.php',
        onSuccess: function(responseText){
            MochaUI.updateContent({
                element: $('mainPanel'),
                content: responseText,
                title: 'Test Post Stuff durrrrrr',
                padding: { top: 8, right: 8, bottom: 8, left: 8 }
            });
        },
    }).send($('stp1_form').toQueryString());
    myRequest.send();
});
</script>
```

hurrrrrr durrrrrr